# Can mana be recovered into your personal pool, once its in the bank?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I can see when I enter the bank that I can press right trigger to add mana in my personal supply to the bank, and I can then later use it on weapons.  I have plenty of banked mana now, is there any way to pull it back into my personal supply (for building towers during a wave when I run out?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, once the mana has been stored it can't be pulled out to be used as building.